# OMNET++: How to replace INET 4.0 submodules in my custom inherited module?

Tags: omnet++, inet, nic

I have an AdhocHost which is inherited from INET's own AdhocHost module, however, I wish to replace the Network Interface Card (wlan) with the one I have manually developed. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... so after digging into INET's code, I found out that it's easily possible using the `typename` parameter.

I simply had to add the following line to the parameters section of my CustomAdhoc.ned:

```
wlan[*].typename = default("myCustomNic");
```

Comment: Indeed. In INET4 we have rewritten all parametrized modules to use the `typename` keyword. I would add that the default() keyword is NOT needed in the above example, as you obviously want to set the value and not just the default value.